# Are the Aelfinn and Eelfinn outside the pattern?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Are the Aelfinn and Eelfinn outside the pattern?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aelfinn_and_Eelfinn#Habitat):

> The Aelfinn and Eelfinn live in twisted worlds, which allow them to read the Pattern more effectively than humans may.

Or does the pattern encompass multiple worlds/dimensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick search of the [Interview Database](http://www.theoryland.com/wheel-of-time-interview-search.php) doesn't turn up a direct answer.

However, I believe the 'Finn are inside the Pattern. I shall outline my reasoning below.

The Pattern includes all worlds, parallel worlds, mirror worlds, everything that has existed and will exist. See for example, Verin's conversation with Egwene when the Dream ter'angreal is handed over in [TDR 21](http://encyclopaedia-wot.org/books/tdr/ch21.html). It has been [confirmed](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=198#7) that the 'Finns world is a parallel world.

The only things we know of that exists outside the Pattern are The Dark One, and The Creator.

As for their abilities, it's not unprecedented for those inside the Pattern to be able to read the Pattern. See Mins viewings, see Foretelling and Prophecy.

So no, I believe the 'Finn are part of The Pattern.

Comment: Thank you. I suddenly had the thought that since Lanfear died in the Aelfinn world and was then resurrected by the Dark One, their world should be part of the pattern. But, as you say, the Dark One too is outside the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

This topic has been debated for a while and their are no hard answers to the Question.[*The Wheel of Time Wiki*](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Finn) states that:

> Collectively, the name of two species of extradimensional humanoids, the Aelfinn and their counterparts the Eelfinn. Each live in a dimension quite different from that of the real world, seemingly apart yet connected.

While [The 13th Depository](http://13depository.blogspot.com/2002/03/aelfinn-and-eelfinn.html) has an interview with Robert Jordan with him saying:

> The Aelfinn and Eelfinn are a pair of nonhuman races who inhabit realms separate from the main world of the Wheel. Jordan answered some questions about them at Dragoncon in September 2005:
>   Do the Finns inhabit a perpendicular world? No, it is a parallel world.
>   Does the physical location of the world of Finns have anything to do with the bells ringing when the ta’veren were in together? No.
>   Have the Finns existed as long as the Wheel? Yes.
>   Do they have souls? Yes.
>   Are the Finns from human stock? No.
>   Did they originate in their current location? Yes.
>   Are they related to Tel’aran’rhiod or do they control Tel’aran’rhiod? No.

So I assume with the fact that they have souls that they are a part of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Wheel of Time Companion* it specifically states that the Eelfinn and Aelfinn possess souls, live in a different world whose location is unknown, and have existed as long as the Wheel. This reinforces early discussions and information regarding the Finn, but unfortunately doesn't tell us specifically about whether or not they're part of the Pattern.

However, I think that telling us they have souls, and have existed as long as the Wheel, is as good as telling us that they're part of the Pattern.

We *do* know now that the Pattern encompasses many worlds, such as those reached through Portal Stones and *tel'aran'rhiod*. The only confirmed being outside the Pattern is The Dark One, and presumably also the Creator.